# SentenceTransformer ('distilbert-base-nli-mean-tokens') is very slow

Tags: python, performance, sentence-transformers, distilbert

I am trying to learn the use of BERT.
Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
data = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all')['data']

from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('distilbert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
embeddings = model.encode(data, show_progress_bar=True)
```

The problem is that it is incredibly slow: 24-48 hours to complete.

I have macOS M1 Pro notebook.
What can be done to speed-up the process?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe the problem is you are not using GPU, but CPU?

Comment: @dankal444 you mean adding: embeddings = model.encode(data, show_progress_bar=True, device='cuda') ?

Comment: I don't know specifics of this library and how to make it use GPU. Just saying your timings suggest that you are not using GPU. You can look at your CPU/GPU usage during encoding.